# Как заблокировать пользовательскую функцию для события копирования в JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт, на котором при копировании срабатывает пользовательская функция, которая добавляет к скопированному тексту дополнительный текст, а также убивает всю разметку, сливая все абзацы в один сплошной текст, теряя при этом заголовки и т.п.

Возможно ли как-нибудь запретить выполнение пользовательской функции для события копирования. Ну или после загрузки всего сайта хотя бы выполнить `document.removeEventListener('copy', addLink);`

Из консоли разработчика выполнить не получится, т.к. ранее привязка была сделана внутри анонимной функции jQuery: `$(function() { ... document.addEventListener('copy', addLink); ... function addLink() { .. } }`.

Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: функция `off` у jQuery если ей передали только имя события удаляет **все** обработчики, возможно навешанные с помощью jquery

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386300/javascript-dom-how-to-remove-all-events-of-a-dom-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставить код в консоль разработчика и все будет работать:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', e => e.stopPropagation(), true);
```

Здесь используется [назначение](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) обработчика на [стадию захвата](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow). Обработчики этой стадии вызываются первыми, раньше чем обработчики дочерних элементов или стадии всплытия. После перехвата события его распространение останавливается при помощи метода [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), отменяя остальные обработчики.

Работать это будет для всех случаев, если только страница сама не назначила обработчик стадии захвата для документа целиком.

Для ленивых сделал расширение для Google Chrome, пока только для него, но может пригодится для таких случаев:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/truecopy?hl=ru

Comment: постарайся писать более развернутые ответы.Допиши в ответ что делает твой код

Comment: он делает именно то о чем я спрашивал, а именно блокирует выполнение пользовательской функции навешанной на событие копирования.

Comment: Добавь пояснение непосредственно в ответ. Желательно с объяснением как это работает

Comment: @Grundy, зачем?

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что блок кода ничего не говорит :-) Ответы только из кода - плохие и никак не помогают понять _почему_ этот код сработал

Comment: @Grundy, Gooooooooogle помогает тем, кому интересно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, гугл должен вести сюда :-) а не отсюда должны все идти в гугл :)

Comment: @Grundy, гули ведёт сюда к целому ответу, ты потрошишь ответ на части и с частями идёшь в гугл, который посылает в документацию на MDN ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, так зачем потрошить? если автор ответа может сразу все описать хорошо? :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53116/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-grundy).

Comment: По ссылке ничего не находит

Comment: @Grundy, очень странно, я проверял даже анонимусом: http://joxi.ru/Vrw9lN3tEMG32X